# Получение определенных данных из бд

Tags: php, redbeanphp

Мне нужно найти запись в бд, по двум полям id и name.

id хранится в `$userid = $_SESSION['logged_user']->id;` **= 1**

name передается ajax запросом `$_POST['name']` **= 'objects'**

таблица 'tests' в бд [image: таблица 'tests' в бд]

Пробую делать так:

```
<?php
require "db.php";
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$get_result = ['auth' => false];
if (isset($_SESSION['logged_user'])) {
  // Получаем id users чья сессия
  $userid = $_SESSION['logged_user']->id;
  // Загружаем данные об этом user
  $user = R::Load('users', $userid);
  //В цикле ниже не выполняется условие
  foreach ($user->ownTestList as $test) {
    if ($test->name == $_POST['name']) {
      $progress = $test->progress;
      $time = $test->time;
    }
  } 
  //заносим все полученные данные в массив чтобы обработать на стороне js
  $get_result = ['result' => $progress, 'time' => $time, 'auth' => true];
}
echo json_encode($get_result);
die();
?>
```

Пробовал так:

```
 $test = R::findOne('tests', 'name = ?', array($_POST['name']));
   if ($test) {
     $progress = $test->progress;
     $time = $test->time;
   }
```

Но все равно, в результате я получаю null [image: Консоль]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот как должен выглядеть правильный вариант:

```
foreach( $user->ownTestsList as $test ) {
    //при каждой итерации записываем в $testName name из бд
    $testName = $test->name;
    //А уже после проверяем этот $testName на тот, что нужен
    if ($testName == $_POST['name']) {
      $progress = $test->progress;
      $time = $test->time;
      //Выходим из цикла 
      break;
    }
  }
```